# How to inject partial pages into main page using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

- I have a webpage in the below design.
- On the left side, I have nav-bar, containing links.
- On selection of the link from the left nav-bar, the partial page should be injected on the right side, i.e inside the main page.
- I don't want to use `ui-router` and `ng-switch`, because they are not performance efficient.

  Can I do this by creating `custom-directive`?

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-include`:

> ng-include get `variable` for example if in your controller have `$scope.template = 'view.html'` you can use it as: `<div ng-include="template"></div>`

```
<div ng-include="'view.html'"></div>
```

in this case we use it as `string`.

To create something like router you can use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` to relation between your links and partials **but** this doesn't change the url at all and for that you can set it manually.

**This is work on your localhost, we didn't have html here**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $filter) {

  var routes = [{
      name: "home",
      html: "home.html"
    },
    {
      name: "about",
      html: "about.html"
    }

  ]

  $scope.changeRoute = function(target) {
    $scope.target = $filter('filter')(routes, {
      name: target
    })[0];
  }
  
   $scope.changeRoute('home')

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1>header</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeRoute('home')">
            <a>home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeRoute('about')">
            <a>about</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
          <h1>{{target.name}}</h1>
          <small>uncomment ng-include on your localhost</small>
          <!-- div ng-include="target.html"></div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: how can i inject page on link selection?

Comment: it's not inject but you can modeling as router, answer updated

Comment: Ok, thanks, but how can I do this using `custom-directives`?

Comment: it's easy by some R & D, then if you didn't find create your sample here again and users or me will answer it, but for this question i think this is your answer

Comment: I have asked question with custom-directives